# merging ecw images

Tags: merge, ecw

Is anyone able to recommend a program/process/method for merging ecw images together.  I have approximately 2000 ecw images (tile) that 1.5x1.5km each which together and put to combine them all together to make one mosaics there is no overlap but each tile abuts exactly to the next.  Collectively they equate to approximately 100gb.

Any ideas?

Comment: With which program you are going to use the merged image? Perhaps it is not necessary to mosaic them physically but only logically through an image catalog.

Answer (score 3):

Few years ago I did the same job very successfully with AU ECW Compressor (I've merged 49 ECWs or 7x7, into one ECW).

**It's free**, also it's a very small program and easy to use. You could also make/save settings as scripts and run it later.

http://www.advisory-unit.org.uk/site/aegis3/aegis_ecw.html

> The Free Advisory Unit ECW Compressor is a simple application for
>   compressing images into ECW format.
>
> It can accept a number of images that are all the same width and
>   height.
>
> Just drag them on to the grid and press the compress button. You can
>   also add grid references to create georeferenced files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many Desktop-GIS use GDAL to read/write raster files so you could try using GDAL direct.

You can get it from the [download page of GDAL](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries). Make sure you install a version, that supports the creation of ECW files. On Windows, that would be for example V1.10.1 from [GisInternals](https://web.archive.org/web/20140425064053/http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1600-x64-gdal-1-10-1-mapserver-6-4-0.zip). Have a special look at the licensing issue of ERDAS of the [ECW Lib 3.3](https://gdal.org/frmt_ecw.html)!

1. Merge your ECW files to a Virtual Raster file (*.vrt) with [gdalbuildvrt](https://gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html)

> gdalbuildvrt MergedRaster.vrt *.ecw
> 2. Translate the Virtual Raster to an ECW file with [gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)
> gdal_translate -of ECW -co "LARGE_OK=YES" MergedRaster.vrt MergedRaster.ecw

ECW is said to have tested file sizes up to 50 Tera Byte. I personally created files with sizes up to 40 GByte.